# Angular render on new data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have implemented a simple chat application with Angular. I am using stomp socket from `@stomp/ng2-stompjs`. I am using `*ngFor` for displaying all meesages.

```
<p *ngFor="let item of messages" style="padding: 5px; font-size: 18px">
    <span style="color:darkturquoise">{{item.author}}</span>: {{item.message}}
  </p>
```

But when `messages` variable is updated (I can see console.log), angular will not rerender `*ngFor`.

```
this.subscription = this.messagesObs.subscribe((message: Frame) => {
  this.messages = <ResponseMessage[]>JSON.parse(message.body).slice();
  console.log(this.messages);
});
```

I have tried `this.changeDetector.detectChanges();`, but it does not help.
I know that this is default behavior of framework but is there any GOOD way how to make `*ngFor` render after each subscription?

Update:

I made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JNDYavs3giLY3hLdaVni?p=preview) example. Example will not work as my backend is on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rxjs `map` operator and the `async`-pipe from angular to subscribe to your data. Also the pipe will make sure that the subscription is cleared if the component is destroyed.

```
public messages$: Observable<ResponseMessage[]> = this.messagesObs.map((message: Frame) => {
  return JSON.parse(message.body) as ResponseMessage[];
});
```

And in you components view:

```
<p *ngFor="let item of messages$ | async" style="padding: 5px; font-size: 18px">
  <span style="color:darkturquoise">{{item.author}}</span>: {{item.message}}
</p>
```

Comment: This work only partially. When I send message, data will come (looked in console) but ngFor is not rendered .. only when i start type another message ...

Comment: How does your `messagesObs` look like? And are you using `onPush` as change detection strategy?

Comment: this https://pastebin.com/gQbUb26h is my .component.ts 
this https://pastebin.com/YDN179F7 is my .html
i have tried OnPush but does not help :)

Comment: I looked at the component and the ng2-stomp service api documentation, this one should work: [**pastebin**](https://pastebin.com/pnsJhePX).

Comment: it is same as mine :) ... does not help

Comment: Is `JSON.parse(message.body)` always returning an array of messages?

Comment: I have spring backed and it is returning list of messages so yes .. AS i said i always get data but it IS  rendered only when i start type another message